# find and remove words from a string that's initiated in database

Tags: javascript, database, string, socket.io

It's my first time working with database using socket.io and I keep running into a problem. 
I have a number of objects in my database labeled as "artid,artimg,artimg". Artid has multiple entries that were labeled "Artifact001", "Artifact002", "Artifact003" etc. I'm trying to remove the word "Artifact" from the string leaving only numbers. But when I'm trying to use .replace expression it messes up with the line localStorage.getItems() instead of what's inside 'artid'. Is it possible to edit artid, or would I have to do it directly in the database? Please advise.

```
socket.on('toClient', function (data) {
  for (var i = 0; i <data.DBarray.length ; i++) {
    console.log(data.DBarray[i]);
    localStorage.setItem(i.toString()+"artid", data.DBarray[i].artid);
    //omit other values for now
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('localStorage length: ' + (localStorage.length)/8);
  for (var i = 0; i < (localStorage.length)/8; i++) {   
    $("ul").append("<li><h3 class='artifact_id'>"+localStorage.getItem(i.toString()+'artid')+"</h3></li>");
    artid = artid.replace(/ *\b\S*?Artifact\S*\b/g, '');
}
```

Comment: While reading through your post I can't find the declaration of `artid` in the last line. Is this the full code? Because the posted code should work without an error except for the last line.

Comment: Mouser, this is not a full code. artid is declared before as var artid. The output of artid is "artifact#". My goal is to get rid off "artifact" in the sentence, but I'm unsure how to access it

Answer (score 0):

In your `for...loop` try this:

```
artid = localStorage.getItem(i.toString()+'artid').replace(/ *\b\S*?Artifact\S*\b/g, '');
$("ul").append("<li><h3 class='artifact_id'>"+artid +"</h3></li>");
```

That should grab the value from `localStorage`, strip out the `artifact` and store it into a variable, which you can print onto the page.

Comment: Thank you Mouser, but this just gets rid of the whole thing.